# Differentiating the map $x\mapsto x/\langle x,x\rangle$ on an inner product space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inner-products

> Let E be a vectorial space of finite dimension. $E^*=E\setminus \{0\}$. $$f:E^*\rightarrow E^*$$
>   $$x\rightarrow \frac{x}{\langle x,x\rangle}$$
>   Is this function $C^1$?

How should I proceed?
My guess is evaluate $f(x+h)-f(x)$ for a small increment $h$ and obtain the differential, then check continuity.
But then I start to operate and the norm gets in the way, I really don't know how to deal with it.
Do I need to go through $\langle x+h,x+h \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle + \langle x,h \rangle + \langle h,x \rangle + \langle h,h\rangle$ ?

I know that the continuity is given by the dimension of the space E, since the differential is a linear map and the space is finite, it's continuous. So that's done, but again, how do I find the differential?

Comment: What do you mean by $E^*$? What if $x = 0$? Can you write this function as a composition of $C^1$ functions?

Comment: What do you name $E^*$? The dual space? If yes, how do you define $\langle x,y \rangle$ for $x,y \in E^*$?

Comment: Sorry, E* is just E without 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is indeed $\mathcal{C}^1$.

To prove it, apply the chain rule.

$\varphi_1 : x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert^2 = \langle x,x \rangle$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and you have $d\varphi_1(x).h = 2 \langle x,h \rangle$.

The real function $\varphi_2 : t \mapsto \frac{1}{t}$ is also $\mathcal{C}^1$ with $d \varphi_2(t)= -\frac{1}{t^2}$.

Now, you have $$f(x)=(\varphi_2 \circ \varphi_1)(x) \cdot x$$ Applying the chain rule, you get $$df(x).h=-2\frac{\langle x,h \rangle}{\langle x, x\rangle^2} x +\frac{h}{\langle x,x \rangle}$$

The result can also be achieved looking at the coordinates as you mentioned that $\dim E$ is finite, let's say equal to $n \ge 1$. You have:
$$f(x_1, \dots, x_n)=(\frac{x_1}{x_1^2+ \dots +x_n^2}, \dots , \frac{x_n}{x_1^2+ \dots +x_n^2})=(f_1(x_1, \dots,x_n), \dots,f_n(x_1, \dots,x_n)).$$ From there you can compute $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. However, on my side, I much prefer the first way which enables to stay at the vector level and is also valid for infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: The first part is what I was looking for. Thank you. Follow-up question: To prove f is a diffeomorphism how would you proceed? I think all you need to see is that f is bijective.

Comment: Since f is C1 so would be $f^{-1}$ if it existed.

Comment: To prove that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, you'll need to prove that (1) $f$ is bijective and $2$ that $f^\prime(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in E \setminus \{0\}$.